# simple prime finder freezing due to large integers C++

Tags: c++, integer, primes, freeze, largenumber

I took it upon myself to learn C++ a few days ago.  I have just written a program to find prime numbers, up to a user inputted value, and write these values to a file.  The program works fine with numbers up to the order of 100,000 - 500,000.  But, if I try to go to 1,000,000 the program freezes.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
long pp, z,counter,lim,indyCounter;
bool isPrime=false;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("E:\\Program Files (x86)\\C++ Programs\\PrimeFinder\\Primes.txt");

cout<<"up to what number would you like to calculate primes? ";
cin>>lim;
cout<<endl;
long ps[lim]; //real-time array of primes

pp=3; //prospective prime
ps[0]=2; //initializing prime array with first prime number
counter=1;
indyCounter=1;

for(int y=1; y<=lim;y++)
{
    ps[y]=1;
}

for(int z=0; z<=lim; z++)
{
    for(int x=0;x<counter;x++)
    {
        if(pp%ps[x]!=0)
        {
            isPrime = true;
        }
        if(pp%ps[x]==0 && ps[x]!=1)
        {
            isPrime=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime)
    {
        ps[indyCounter]=pp;
        indyCounter++;
    }
    counter++;
    pp++;
}

for(int y=0; y<=lim-1;y++)
{
    if(ps[y]!=1)
    {
        myfile<<ps[y]<<endl;
    }
}

myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

please excuse my beginners code, and all advice is much appreciated!
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Use Pointer instead of real time array. because array has a limit for allocation which get corrupted after a certain use.

Comment: @HeenaGoyal: Wat? The array might not fit onto the stack, but that would just abort the program, not cause silent corruption.

Answer (score 0):

The default stack size on Windows is only 8MB, and an array of 1000000 longs requires 8MB, so you're overflowing the stack.  You need to allocate your array on the heap instead.